# How do I incorporate sed commands to perl script?

Tags: perl, sed

I am trying to incorporate these basic sed commands into my perl script.

```
sed "1,$s/^/20181230,/g" usd_jan_ora.txt > u2_1231.txt
sed "1,$s/,2018-12-3[0-9]T[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]+0000//g" u2_1231.txt > u3_1231.txt
sed "1,$s/\([A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]\),[0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/\1/g" u3_1231.txt > u4_1231.txt
```

Although there have been multiple posts about this, I am still new to perl and I have difficulty translating those answers to my specific problem.

So far I have written this script to navigate to a url and download the webpage as txt file. Now I need to edit this text file to the format needed for the next step.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use HTML::FormatText;
use LWP::Simple;


my      $dateField = 'date=2018-12-31';
my      $currency  = "USD";
my      $filename = 'C:\Users\My.Name\Downloads\doc3.txt';
my      $address = "my.url";
my      $content = get($address);

my $s = 1;

defined $content or die "Cannot read '$address': $!";

my $string = HTML::FormatText->format_string
(
    $content,
    leftmargin  =>  5,
    rightmargin => 75,
);

open(my $file, '>', $filename) or die $!;
print $file $string;

my $cmd = "sed '1,$s/^/20181230,/g' doc3.txt > test.txt";

print "Launching [$cmd]\n";

system($cmd) == 0
    or die "Couldn't launch [$cmd]: $! / $?";
```

Comment: Just run the substitutions directly in Perl, no need to shell out to sed. It will be faster anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so your sed commands are changing the length of the text, so you really need to be doing the alterations before formatting the output, so it really needs doing between the `defined $content ...` and `my $string ...` lines.

The sed commands are doing multiple selections across each line of the document. This can be done directly in Perl with a few tweaks to go from sed regex to Perl regex

```
$content =~ s/^/20181230,/gm; # The m option makes ^ match at the start of each line
$content =~ s/,2018-12-3[0-9]T[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\+0000//g;
$content =~ s/([A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]),[0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/$1/g;
```

Then you can format the content and print it to your final file.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help! it was really detailed and I learned from it. One more question. what sed command can i use to remove a particular string from the text?

Comment: You can use the substitute command with a blanc substitution like the second of your sed commands